# How to exchange this double sum?

Tags: summation

I have a sequence of sets $D_i$, and currently the sum is
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{d\in D_i} 1 
$$

How would I exchange the sum so that we run through $i$ first?

Comment: What is *concretely* $D_i$? Trivially the sum is $|D_1| + \cdots + |D_n|$.

Comment: They're just sets. I originally went from 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |D_i|
$$
and wanted to use the OP summation to see the sum in a different expression.   
Does the exchange depend on what $D_i$ specifically is?

Comment: Assuming $D_i \subseteq D$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$, where $D$ is some finite or countably infinite set, you could write:$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{d \in D_i}1 = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{d \in D} 1_{\{d \in D_i\}}=\sum_{d\in D} \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\{d \in D_i\}}$$ where $1_{\{d \in D_i\}}$ is an indicator function that is 1 if $d \in D_i$ and 0 else.

Comment: @Michael: a better notation will be $$\sum_{d\in D}\ \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\scriptscriptstyle D_{\ i}}(d)$$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla : Thanks. I've always written such things like $1_{\{d \in D_i\}}$, or $1_A$ in general for a particular "event" $A$ of interest.  It seems like that way places less burden on the reader to remember notation:  If we see $\{d \in D_i\}$ we know that $D_i$ is some set and $d$ is an element of it.  Perhaps I will try your notation sometime, one advantage of $1_{D_i}(d)$ is that it emphasizes the functional dependence on the $d$ parameter.